# Dice Roll, Kelly Criterion and Ralph Vince Optimal F

Tags: optimization, dice, gambling

I read an article of betting on a six-sided die whereby:

If an even number comes up, the gain = bet amount x even number

If an odd number comes up, the loss = bet amount x odd number

For example:
If one bets \$10 and the number that comes up is 2, then the gain is \$10 x 2 = \$20

Using the same \$10 bet and the number on the next roll is 5, the loss is $10 x 5 = \$50

Since one can lose up to five times the wager amount, the most one could possibly bet is 1/5 of one's bankroll.

Using Python, the author mentions in the article that the Kelly Criterion = 0.025 or 2.5% and Ralph Vince Optimal f = 0.034 or 3.4%

I am able to generate the same Ralph Vince Optimal f by maximizing the TWR function in Excel which is 3.37436% to be more precise but I need help with how the author generates the Kelly Criterion of 2.5%.

Here is the attached google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aKm78Y3P4fBaLQca0OTXlBmt5_TyoFSJ78U5Xsx_pQw/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I am confused as to what the question is that you want answered.  It is clear that if you bet $(1)$ unit, six times, you should expect to win $(2 + 4 + 6)$ units and lose $(1 + 3 + 5)$ units.  So, on each bet, you should expect to win $(0.5)$ units.  What Mathematical question are you asking?

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I do know how to calculate the expected value.
The mathematical question I am asking is how to calculate the Kelly Criterion of 2.5% for the above scenario in Excel or google sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [this article](https://quantfiction.com/2018/05/06/position-sizing-for-practitioners-part-1-beyond-kelly/), IMO its representation of the Kelly criterion is a bit uncharitable to Kelly. The *very first formula* in [Kelly's original 1956 paper](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ewbialek/rome/refs/kelly_56.pdf) is

$$
G = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \log{\frac{V_N}{V_0}}
$$

so Kelly's intent was always to maximize the logarithm of the bankroll and not the arithmetic mean. Here is example code:

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize

def kelly(returns):
    def fun(x):
        after = 1.0 + x * returns
        if numpy.any(after <= 0.0):
            return numpy.inf
        return -numpy.mean(numpy.log(after))
    result = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, 0.0)
    return result

returns = numpy.array([-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6])

print(kelly(returns))
```

So what the article calls the "optimal f" *is* the Kelly criterion, and what the article calls the "Kelly criterion" just retrofitted an arithmetic mean on top of Kelly's solution to the binary case.

Comment: Thank you for straighten up the information in the article!
Yes, I am referring to that article you provided.
I am not familiar with Python and hence I'm not able to understand the code.
I am trying to calculate how the author comes up with 2.5% but using Excel or google sheet to get my understanding right between Kelly and Optimal f.